# Getting the top sales

Tags: mysql, sql

How to i get the top vendor for each country? I have this code and it shows the connection between the two tables, now I have to get the largest gmv per country.

Here is my working code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.country_name, b.vendor_name, 
       SUM(a.gmv_local) as total_gmw
 from `my-project-67287.order1.order2`a
 join `my-project-67287.vendor1.vendor2` b on a.vendor_id = b.id 
 group by a.country_name, b.vendor_name;
```

[image]

The top 3 should show this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can save that `SELECT` into a table called `vendors`, you need to use it as the subquery in the `FROM` clause.
You could use this:

```
SELECT vendors.country_name, vendors.vendor_name, MAX(vendors.total_gmw)
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT a.country_name, b.vendor_name, 
           SUM(a.gmv_local) as total_gmw
     from `my-project-67287.order1.order2`a
     join `my-project-67287.vendor1.vendor2` b on a.vendor_id = b.id 
     group by a.country_name, b.vendor_name
) AS vendors
GROUP BY vendors.country_name;
```

I must mention I have not tested your query, since I do not have your tables, so I assumed it's correct.
I only created the `vendors` table with the required fields and values from your picture. This should print:

[image]

Comment: thanks for this! now, the only error is this:SELECT list expression references vendors.vendor_name which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:30]

Comment: My mistake, I was using SQLite. For MySQL, that is because vendor_name is not in the group by clause. By default, in MySQL, you need to have every column you select (except aggregation functions) inside the group by  clause. You can remove the default ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from mysql console using this command: 
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','')); 
Then the code should work.

Comment: hey alin thanks for this, i have added the vendor_name in the clause but now, sum of all vendors show.

Comment: select * from vendors 
where total_gmw IN (select max(total_gmw) from vendors group by country_name);

I have tested this query in MySQL and it works. Now, adding your query in the second "from" clause in place of vendors as  another subquery should work. Make sure the query is inside parentheses and without the trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT odr.c_name,vdr.v_name,odr.gmv
FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM(
        SELECT c_name,v_id,gmv
        FROM `order`
        ORDER BY gmv DESC
    )
    GROUP BY c_name
)AS odr
LEFT JOIN vender AS vdr ON vdr.id = odr.v_id
GROUP BY odr.c_name
```

c_name short for country_name

Comment: hi! thanks for this, the error now shows that the c_name is not aggregated?